# Performing firebase query on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, I'm wanting to perform a search on data so that it returns a list of users that match the search (kinda like how Facebook or Twitter does their searches) so I have a couple questions since this is very hard to find online. First, users enter data into a SearchView. I have set an `onQueryTextListener` and am searching the Firebase database once the user hits submit. To retrieve of query of all data that begins with the string entered, I have this code (I understand it might be entirely wrong):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("uploads").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().orderByChild("username").startAt(s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

My first question is this: is this a good way of retrieving all of the users that have a username that matches the specified search? This is what my database is structured as: [image: Firebase database]

If this is correct, what can i do with the query? can it be treated as a hashmap of User objects? Or does it act like nothing? I'm not sure how to deal with it once I'm finished. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the query working?

Comment: @PeterHaddad by "working" do you mean is it getting an actual value? If so, then yes it is getting a value. Although I'm not exactly sure what this value is

Comment: is it not getting the list of usernames?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know what it is supposed to return. How should i get the values that it is returning? I am honestly generally clueless about the `Query` data type.

Comment: I added a log within the `onChildAdded` method like such: `Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: " + query.toString());` and this is what I got in return: `onChildAdded: com.google.firebase.database.Query@a1299e2`. That's as much as I have right now :)

Comment: alright check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 DatabaseReference db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("uploads");
   db.orderByChild("username").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
              String usernames=dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();

            }
```

This would get you all the usernames in the database. If you want only one username then you can do this:

```
db.orderByChild("username").equalTo(one_username_value_or_variable).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){....}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got every username back that was in my database. I cannot thank you enough since I've been stuck on this for days :D

Comment: Just to add a small note, if you want to use complex queries like "%had%" then you can't do that on Firebase. You need to use Elastic Search then. A blog post for that is here. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/01/queries-part-2-advanced-searches-with.html